# Regular expression match integers without commas

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Using JavaScript and Node I have a text file with contents as such:

```
             The First 1,000,000 Primes (from primes.utm.edu)

     2         3         5         7        11        13        17        19 

    23        29        31        37        41        43        47        53 

    59        61        67        71        73        79        83        89 

    97       101       103       107       109       113       127       131
```

I have read the file contents and now want to match the integer values, ignoring the number with commas in the title. I am not allowed to edit the file.

I have tried `/\d+/` but I get [these matches](https://regex101.com/r/dRaquW/2):

1
000
000
2
3
5
etc

I just want the integer prime numbers. Many thanks.

Comment: Use `/(?:^|[^\d,])(\d+)(?![,\d])/g` and grab Group 1 values. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xVMW13/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break lines, throw away the first line, and then apply your regex. Something like

```
var numbersString = fileTxt.split('\n').slice(1).join('\n');
```

Then do your regex on numbersString

pd: edited because shift returns the removed line, so it needs to be slice to be a oneliner

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to ensure that the matched digits are preceeded by a space, and followed by a space. You can do this with lookbehind, although in many environments, it's not supported:

```
(?<= )\d+(?= )
```

https://regex101.com/r/dRaquW/4

Without lookbehind, *match* the leading space instead, and *capture* the digits in a group:

```
\s(\d+)(?= )
```

https://regex101.com/r/dRaquW/5